# How to disable @Generated annotation in Immutable generated class?

Tags: java, immutables-library

I am using Immutables-value for defining my POJO. And when it generates the Immutable* class, it has the @Generated annotation at the top. Is there any way I could disable it?

I checked in their codebase:
https://github.com/immutables/immutables/blob/master/value-annotations/src/org/immutables/value/Generated.java#L22-L27

It is mentioned here that it can be disabled by : 
Style#allowedClasspathAnnotations()

I used it on top of POJO interface like this:

```
@Value.Style(allowedClasspathAnnotations = {org.immutables.value.Generated.class})
```

But still I am getting the @Generated annotation on top of my generated class. Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

@Style's `allowedClasspathAnnotations` attribute whitelists the annotations you included there (Rather than blacklisting them). See [here](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/blob/master/value-annotations/src/org/immutables/value/Value.java#L1333-L1379).

So if you want to only disable `org.immutables.value.Generated` you should instead do something like:

```
@Value.Style(allowedClasspathAnnotations = {
  javax.annotation.concurrent.Immutable,
  javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault,
  javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue,
  edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings,
  com.google.errorprone.annotations.Var,
  com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable
})
```

To whitelist the annotations you want to keep.